# MS Access Multiple Inner Joins

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I have this sql query

```
SELECT e.permission_name 
FROM ((((users_roles a 
          INNER JOIN users b 
          ON a.user_id = b.id) 
         INNER JOIN roles c 
         ON a.role_id = c.id) 
        INNER JOIN roles_permissions d 
        ON c.id = d.role_id) 
       INNER JOIN permissions e 
       ON d.permission_id = e.id) 
WHERE b.id = :id
```

I've added the parentheses since MS Access requires it but it's not working.

I'm using MS Access in PHP

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Remove the ()'s let access add them back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to put brackets it might give you a syntax error. Just remove braces

```
SELECT e.permission_name 
FROM users_roles a 
INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id
INNER JOIN roles c ON a.role_id = c.id
INNER JOIN roles_permissions d N c.id = d.role_id
INNER JOIN permissions e ON d.permission_id = e.id
WHERE b.id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT p.permission_name 
FROM (((users_roles as ur INNER JOIN
        users as u
        ON ur.user_id = u.id
       ) INNER JOIN
       roles as r 
       ON ur.role_id = r.id
      ) INNER JOIN
      roles_permissions as rp
     ON r.id = rp.role_id
     ) INNER JOIN
     permissions as p
     ON rp.permission_id = p.id
WHERE u.id = :id;
```

The only real difference from your version is the use of `as` for the table aliases.